# ORA-01722: invalid number oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello guys am running below query but i got

> ORA-01722: invalid number

the problem is in the last line **AND H.DATE_END<=S.END_DATE**
if i run query with the last condition it will work fine

notes :  H.DATE_END and S.END_DATE are date data type

```
SELECT H.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
     S.SALARY_ID
     FROM UNPAID_LEAVES H,
          MEMBERS M,
          EMPLOYMENTS E,
          SALARIES S

       WHERE  H.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = M.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
          AND M.MERGE_ID = E.MERGE_ID
          AND E.EMPLOYMENT_ID = S.EMPLOYMENT_ID
          AND H.START_DATE >=  S.START_DATE 
          AND H.DATE_END<=S.END_DATE
```

Comment: You've provided no information about your database schema and no sample data from the tables. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a  very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Comment: Why are you choosing to not use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Probably, adding the last condition changes the execution plan and so implicit to_number cast occurs on one of previous conditions. Check the execution plan for implicit to_number casts and add to_char wrap to avoid it.